# Can't assign value to object's property

Tags: python, oop, object

I have really weird problem. I wrote one class, then I wanted to modify her a bit. I changed few things and now:

```
class Window (Drawable):
__width = 0

def __init__(self, intext="", intitle="", inwidth=50, inheight=10, startpos=Position()):
    self.__width = inwidth
    print inwidth
    print self.__width
```

I'm using this code to present my problem. Whenever I create an object by using this class, it prints 50 and then 0. This is quite weird, cause what I'm doing there is, I think, a basic way to change this value.
What i'm doing wrong?

For a while I thought it's due to this code

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    if key == "position" or key == "width" or key == "height":
        if key == "position":
            self.__position = value
        if key == "width":
            self.__width = value
        if key == "height":
            self.__height = value
        self.__get_shape()
```

But I commented it and nothing changed.
Then I thought it's because variable couldn't be named with underscores, but this isn't true either.
I'm all out of ideas, really.

**Edit:**
Now I found the cause. It's, as I thought, **setattr** - parent class also uses one. Is there any way to make **settattr** works only for other classes, or only for other keys? I want it just to set position, height and width in my way.

Comment: Note that two leading underscores invokes *"name mangling"*, which makes everything more complicated. For a private-by-convention attribute, a single leading underscore is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customising `__setattr__` can be tricky, error-prone, and simply isn't the right tool for the job here.

To customise setters, it would be a better design decision to use python properties rather than muck around with `__setattr__`. Here is a simplified example:

```
class Window(object):
    def __init__(self, width=640):
        self._width = width

    @property
    def width(self):
        """I'm the 'width' property."""
        return self._width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        # your custom setter logic here...
        self._width = value
```

Start reading [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is really helpfull and, I think, this just solved my issue completly

Comment: Excuse me, I used this code like this
`    @property
    def text(self):
        return self.__text

    @text.setter
    def text(self, text):
        print "foo"
        self.__text = text
        self.__get_shape()`
Then I use
`obj.text = "abc"`
But there is no foo output, __get_shape also isn't called. What's wrong?